# How to handle window scroll efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is calling some function when the screen is scrolled above a certain offset.

```
var $window = $(window);
var doFunct = function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 200) {
       console.log('Above 200');
    } else {
       console.log('below 200');
    }
}
$window.scroll(doFunct);
```

What I want to achieve is that the function console logs only whenever the `scrollTop` changes between being above 200 and below it. Not every single time I scroll as it is the case now!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a variable to indicate the threshold has been crossed. Something like:

```
var $window = $(window);
var threshold = false;
var doFunct = function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 200) {
       if(!theshold){
          console.log('Above 200');
          theshold = true;
       }
    } else {
       if(theshold){
          console.log('below 200');
          theshold = false;
       }
    }
}
$window.scroll(doFunct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Self contained version - i.e. no extra "global" vars

```
var $window = $(window);
var doFunct = (function () {
    var isBelow = true; // assuming a page loads with scrollTop == 0
    return function() {
        var top = $window.scrollTop();
        if (top > 200 && isBelow) {
           console.log('Above 200');
           isBelow = false;
        } else if (top <= 200 && !isBelow) {
           console.log('below 200');
           isBelow = true;
        }
    };
}());
$window.scroll(doFunct);
```